# C# how to subscribe to an event that uses a delegate?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I am writing an application that uses a class from a third party.  This class has the following event defined:

```
 public event SamplesAvailableDelegate<ByteSamplesEventArgs> FFTAvailable;
```

and this event is raised in in this class.  I want to subscribe to this event in my Windows Forms application.

I have tried the following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Client _client;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _client = new Client();
        _client.FFTAvailable += _fftAvailable(object sender, ByteSamplesEventArgs e);
    }

    private void _fftAvailable(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do something here
    }
}
```

When I do this I get an error " cannot implicitly convert type void...
Can someone tell me the correct syntax to handle the event please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the solution was simple.  I needed the following:

```
_client.FFTAvailable += _FTTAvailable;
```

and then

```
private void _FFTAvailable(object sender, ByteSamplesEventArgs e)
{

}
```

This works.  Thanks for the help.  I got thrown off declaring the event handler.

Comment: Well, since I've failed to notice the change of the += row in my answer, I've deleted it. Upvoted yours since you've managed to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to share the signature of the delegate `SamplesAvailableDelegate<ByteSamplesEventArgs>`.

`_fftAvailable` is expecting to return some datatype but it is returning void.

Comment: Can you show what the syntax would be for both statements?